# D3js: how to plot multiseries line chart with json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot multiseries line chart witht the below json data where month is a x-axis data, case count y-axis and groupName are lines . I am  having problem in formating a data for the lines.
 I Want a multi series line graph something like this.http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/multi-series/multi-chart.html
 any help is appreciated.

json data

```
[
   {
      "groupName":"Casio GzOne",
      "caseCount":8,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"GALAXY",
      "caseCount":80,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"HTC ",
      "caseCount":14,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"LG Mobile Phones",
      "caseCount":27,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Motorola",
      "caseCount":29,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Nokia Lumia",
      "caseCount":3,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Sony Ericsson Xperia",
      "caseCount":4,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Verizon Ellipsis",
      "caseCount":18,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPhone 5",
      "caseCount":29,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPhone 6",
      "caseCount":33,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"10-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Casio GzOne",
      "caseCount":4,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"DEFAULT",
      "caseCount":32,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"GALAXY",
      "caseCount":83,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"HTC",
      "caseCount":14,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"HTC ",
      "caseCount":7,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"LG Mobile Phones",
      "caseCount":14,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Motorola",
      "caseCount":29,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Nokia Lumia",
      "caseCount":3,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Sony Ericsson Xperia",
      "caseCount":3,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Verizon Ellipsis",
      "caseCount":3,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPHONE",
      "caseCount":14,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPhone 5",
      "caseCount":13,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPhone 6",
      "caseCount":16,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"11-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"DEFAULT",
      "caseCount":15,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"GALAXY",
      "caseCount":22,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Motorola",
      "caseCount":3,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Nokia Lumia",
      "caseCount":1,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"Samsung Galaxy Note",
      "caseCount":4,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   },
   {
      "groupName":"iPhone 6",
      "caseCount":4,
      "caseCreatedMonth":"12-2014"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've based this example on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

Given that the data you have is already in JSON this example needs some changes. See http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/ae5hhv5L/2/embedded/result/ for my version.

Changes are mostly around manipulating the data. To do this you want to `nest` the data so that values (`date` and `casecount`) sit under each `groupname`

```
processeddata = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.groupName;
    })
    .entries(phonedata);
```

After that it's mostly a case of changing data accessor names. For more info on `nest` I always find this page helpful: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/